# CSS issues with float and parent child relationship for borders

Tags: css

I am somewhat new to CSS and do not understand why I am having the following issues with border and float.

Issue 1. My left float will work if I have .main div {float: left;}, but not if I have just .main or div.main?

Issue 2. The parents div's border is also being apllied to the child divs, not sure why?

```
 .main div {float:left; padding:10px; border: 1px solid #000;}

 <div class="main">
    <div> option1</div>
    <div> option2</div>

 </div>
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should consider using `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left` - there is no reason to use floats imo.
2. If you only want to select 1 level down in your markup, use : `.main > div`

Also --> `Issue 1. My left float will work if I have .main div {float: left;}, but not if I have just .main or div.main?`

You are mentioning 3 different selectors:

- `.main div` = all divs that are descendants of elements with the class `main`
- `.main` = only the elements with the class `main`
- `div.main` = all divs that have the class `main`
- `.main > div` = all divs that are children of elements with the class `main`

I think you're trying to do one of the following:

```
.main{display:inline-block;border:1px solid #000;}
.main > div{display:inline-block;padding:10px;}
```

or:

```
.main > div{border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;margin:0 10px;padding:10px;}
```

Comment: That did the trick. The 2nd line with the ">" how does this function? Is it just an expansion of the 1st .main?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the ">" selector to the 3 explanations, added now